# Where is module class defined in Python?

Tags: python, module, built-in, introspection

I can't seem to find where `<type module>` is defined in Python. For example, running the following:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys)
module
>>> sys.__class__  # returns the fact that sys is an instance of the module class
module
>>> sys.__class__.__module__  # this tells us that the "module" class in defined within builtins...
builtins
>>> import builtins  # so lets try to access this module class, say for type hints...
>>> builtins.module  # ... and kablam!!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-740ae1eed4d0> in <module>
----> 1 builtins.module

AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'module
```

Using the official introspection method:

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmodule(sys.__class__)
<module 'builtins' (built-in)>
```

Which agrees with the magic attribute approach before. What is going on? Why can't I access this module class for use in type hint signatures, etc.? Must I use forward refs instead for type hints? Is the module class never intended for access by the user?

Comment: The CPython interpreter has some core Python types that are not defined in Python code but in C. See the [sources](https://github.com/python/cpython) for details.